# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000

Tags: api, docker, nuxt.js

I have two separated projects, the first one is an api created with drupal that expose a json data, the second one is a nuxt project connected to the api.
The problem is when i tried to get a list of articles, i have an error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000
```

Vuejs code

```
      try {
        const articles = await 
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/jsonapi/node/article`)
        return { articles: articles.data.rows }
      } catch (e) {
        error({ message: "Pas d'articles" + e, statusCode: 404 })
      }
```

docker file (nuxt)

```
version: "3"

services:
  nuxt:
    build: ./app/
    container_name: nuxt
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command:
      "npm run start"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - nuxt
```

Docker file for Drupal api :

```
version: "3"

services:
  mariadb:
    image: wodby/mariadb:$MARIADB_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_mariadb"
    stop_grace_period: 30s
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $DB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $DB_NAME
      MYSQL_USER: $DB_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD

  php:
    image: wodby/drupal-php:$PHP_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_php"
    environment:
      PHP_SENDMAIL_PATH: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -S mailhog:1025
      DB_HOST: $DB_HOST
      DB_USER: $DB_USER
      DB_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
      DB_NAME: $DB_NAME
      DB_DRIVER: $DB_DRIVER
      PHP_FPM_USER: wodby
      PHP_FPM_GROUP: wodby
      COLUMNS: 80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
nginx:
    image: wodby/nginx:$NGINX_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx"
    depends_on:
      - php
    environment:
      NGINX_STATIC_OPEN_FILE_CACHE: "off"
      NGINX_ERROR_LOG_LEVEL: debug
      NGINX_BACKEND_HOST: php
      NGINX_SERVER_ROOT: /var/www/html/web
      NGINX_VHOST_PRESET: $NGINX_VHOST_PRESET
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    labels:
      - 'traefik.backend=${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx'
      - 'traefik.port=80'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${PROJECT_BASE_URL}'

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_mailhog"
    labels:
      - 'traefik.backend=${PROJECT_NAME}_mailhog'
      - 'traefik.port=8025'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:mailhog.${PROJECT_BASE_URL}'
portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_portainer"
    command: --no-auth -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    labels:
      - 'traefik.backend=${PROJECT_NAME}_portainer'
      - 'traefik.port=9000'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:portainer.${PROJECT_BASE_URL}'

  traefik:
    image: traefik
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_traefik"
    command: -c /dev/null --web --docker --logLevel=INFO
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

i have two separated environnement, one for drupal api (backend) and the second one is for nuxt project (front)

Answer (score 1):

Inside of a container, localhost or 127.0.0.1 maps to the container, not to the external host, unless you turn off the network namespace (not recommended). We don't see the app listening on 8000 in your question, so the general advice looks like:

Between containers, you need to place both containers on the same user created docker network, connect to the container or service name as the hostname, and connect to the application port, not a published port on the host. Compose sets up the networks for you by default, e.g. from "nuxt" you could `curl http://nginx:80/`.

To talk from the container to an app on the host, not running on a container, either move that app into a container and follow the steps above, or connect to the host DNS or IP rather than localhost.

---

From your edit, the above applies. You can either keep the two projects separate and change the hostname/IP to that of your host. Or you can connect the two projects over a shared network, e.g.:

```
docker network create backend
```

And then add the shared network to each compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  nuxt:
    build: ./app/
    container_name: nuxt
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - default
      - backend
    command:
      "npm run start"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - nuxt
networks:
  backend:
    external: true
```

And for the other project:

```
version: "3"

services:
  mariadb:
    image: wodby/mariadb:$MARIADB_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_mariadb"
    stop_grace_period: 30s
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $DB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $DB_NAME
      MYSQL_USER: $DB_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD

  php:
    image: wodby/drupal-php:$PHP_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_php"
    environment:
      PHP_SENDMAIL_PATH: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -S mailhog:1025
      DB_HOST: $DB_HOST
      DB_USER: $DB_USER
      DB_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
      DB_NAME: $DB_NAME
      DB_DRIVER: $DB_DRIVER
      PHP_FPM_USER: wodby
      PHP_FPM_GROUP: wodby
      COLUMNS: 80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
nginx:
    image: wodby/nginx:$NGINX_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx"
    depends_on:
      - php
    environment:
      NGINX_STATIC_OPEN_FILE_CACHE: "off"
      NGINX_ERROR_LOG_LEVEL: debug
      NGINX_BACKEND_HOST: php
      NGINX_SERVER_ROOT: /var/www/html/web
      NGINX_VHOST_PRESET: $NGINX_VHOST_PRESET
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    labels:
      - 'traefik.backend=${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx'
      - 'traefik.port=80'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${PROJECT_BASE_URL}'

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_mailhog"
    labels:
      - 'traefik.backend=${PROJECT_NAME}_mailhog'
      - 'traefik.port=8025'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:mailhog.${PROJECT_BASE_URL}'
  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_portainer"
    command: --no-auth -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    labels:
      - 'traefik.backend=${PROJECT_NAME}_portainer'
      - 'traefik.port=9000'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:portainer.${PROJECT_BASE_URL}'

  traefik:
    image: traefik
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_traefik"
    command: -c /dev/null --web --docker --logLevel=INFO
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    networks:
    - default
    - backend
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
networks:
  backend:
    external: true
```

And then change your connection from `localhost:8000` to `traefik:80`.

Comment: Docker file for drupal app


`traefik:
    image: traefik
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_traefik"
    command: -c /dev/null --web --docker --logLevel=INFO
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: @hla89 please edit your question to add additional information. Yml files are unreadable in a comment.

Comment: Sorry, i edited the code, i think it's more clear now

Comment: @hla89 did you manage to fix this issue? I have a very similar issue (and a similar Docker setup except, I use a Node.js server for my APis instead of Drupal). How did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your port mapping is wrong. In your docker compose you're mapping nginx port 8081 to port 80 of your computer. Maybe you need to map 8081:8000, provided that your nginx config actually starts a service at port 8081 and makes the appropiate proxy redirections to the nuxt host (nuxt:3000).

Or maybe your vuejs code needs to update port to http://localhost/ since you're mapping to port 80 in your compose file.

Comment: i changed the config like that  8081:8000
but i have always the same problem